# Xamarin.Forms+Prism Navigation target control

Tags: c#, navigation, xamarin.forms, prism

I have a Xamarin app made up of several page types. I'm using Prism.

I'd like the navigation target of the app to be a nested view in the app within the main page, not the main page itself, so that the `MainPage` is used as an outer frame that's always there, and a nested page hosts the app's navigation service.
In this way I can have some controls (i.e. back/forward/home) always present.
How do I configure the `NavigationService`'s '`MainPage`' to be a nested page within the actual `MainPage`?
I'm pretty new to XF, and haven't used the `NavigationPage` before, but could it be of any use here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't. Prism's navigation service will not support what you are trying to do because the `INavigationService` is `Page` based.  It sounds like your approach is very unorthodox.  Why not just use a `NavigationPage` and provide your options in a custom renderer or as toolbar items?

Comment: Just to clarify it's just a month I'm working with XF and still lack a lot of knowledge in it. Based on what I understand from your answer I guess I have two options, either have a custom renderer of my toolbars layout embedded in all the app pages or have a custom page renderer or `ControlTemplate` for the page which has the toolbars embedded. The first option will require adding the toolbar to all pages, while the other one will require making a custom renderer for all page types I'll be using (i.e. `MasterDetailPage`, `CarouselPage` etc.), do I get it right? If yes I go with option 1.

Comment: Or did you suggest I shouldn't use Prism's navigation? I like it because I use AutoWireViewModel and I register the ViewModels for navigation

Comment: Do what works for you. You can use AutowireViewModel on anything that is of type BindableObject

Comment: K. So since I wanna stick to Prism navigation I'll go for the custom view solution.

Answer (score 1):

Prism's `INavigationService` isn't designed to do what you're looking to do. Luckily custom Views are! You could do as previously suggested, but I would generally avoid creating a custom page, and instead create a custom View which would have it's own content property.

#### EDIT:

The terminology can get particularly confusing with Xamarin Forms, especially if you are new to MVVM and Xamarin Forms, and/or have moved from developing on other platforms.

What Xamarin Forms refers to as a `View` is more often referred to as a `Control` on other platforms. This is especially confusing when working with an MVVM framework such as Prism, because our MVVM `Views` are actually Xamarin Forms `Pages`.

While from time to time we need to create a custom type of Page, more often than not, we are just implementing some page type. For instance say I have a page that I am going to use for a Login Page:

LoginPage.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             Title="{Binding Title}"
             x:Class="MyAwesomeApp.Views.LoginPage">

    <Grid BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource primary}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="3*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <Style TargetType="StackLayout">
                    <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="White" />
                    <Setter Property="VerticalOptions" Value="FillAndExpand" />
                </Style>
                <Style TargetType="Entry">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="40,10" />
                </Style>
                <Style TargetType="Button">
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="20" />
                    <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{DynamicResource primaryDark}" />
                    <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="White" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderRadius" Value="5" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderWidth" Value="1" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderColor" Value="Black" />
                </Style>
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </Grid.Resources>

        <Image Source="logo.png" 
               Aspect="AspectFit"
               HorizontalOptions="Center"
               VerticalOptions="Center" />

        <StackLayout Grid.Row="1">
            <Entry Text="{Binding UserName}" 
                   Placeholder="Enter your username"
                   x:Name="userNameEntry"
                   VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand" />
            <Entry Text="{Binding Password}" 
                   Placeholder="Enter your password"
                   IsPassword="True"
                   x:Name="passwordEntry"
                   VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" />
            <Button Text="Submit"
                    Command="{Binding LoginCommand}" />
        </StackLayout>

    </Grid>

</ContentPage>
```

LoginPage.xaml.cs

```
public partial class LoginPage
{
    public LoginPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

While there is a lot going on in the XAML, this is just simply a page that is a ContentPage. It is **NOT** by any Means a Custom Page. You'll notice there is absolutely nothing in the code behind here. I might create some event handlers for instance if the user hits the Done/Enter on the keyboard that they go to the next field or it invokes a button click, but that still does not make this a Custom Page.

For an example of a "Custom Page" you can check out the [XLabs ExtendedTabbedPage](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/blob/master/src/Forms/XLabs.Forms/Controls/ExtendedTabbedPage.cs). One thing you'll notice is there there are several new properties on their version of the TabbedPage. Of course their page only works because of the [renderer](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/blob/master/src/Forms/XLabs.Forms.iOS/Controls/ExtendedTabbedPage/ExtendedTabbedPageRenderer.cs)

Sticking with the example I already showed, let's say we wanted to take the Login Layout that I created in my page and wanted to be able to reuse it across projects, or perhaps on different pages of my App. Then I would want to do something like:

LoginView.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Grid xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
      BackgroundColor="{DynamicResource primary}"
      x:Name="grid"
      x:Class="MyAwesomeApp.Controls.LoginView">

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="3*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="1*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style TargetType="StackLayout">
                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="White" />
                <Setter Property="VerticalOptions" Value="FillAndExpand" />
            </Style>
            <Style TargetType="Entry">
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="40,10" />
            </Style>
            <Style TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="20" />
                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{DynamicResource primaryDark}" />
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="White" />
                <Setter Property="BorderRadius" Value="5" />
                <Setter Property="BorderWidth" Value="1" />
                <Setter Property="BorderColor" Value="Black" />
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <Image Source="logo.png" 
           Aspect="AspectFit"
           HorizontalOptions="Center"
           VerticalOptions="Center" />

    <StackLayout Grid.Row="1" BindingContext="{x:Reference grid}">
        <Entry Text="{Binding UserName}" 
               Placeholder="Enter your username"
               x:Name="userNameEntry"
               VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand" />
        <Entry Text="{Binding Password}" 
               Placeholder="Enter your password"
               IsPassword="True"
               x:Name="passwordEntry"
               VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" />
        <Button Text="Submit"
                Command="{Binding LoginCommand}" />
    </StackLayout>

</Grid>
```

LoginView.xaml.cs

```
public partial class LoginView : Grid
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty UserNameProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(UserName), typeof(string), typeof(LoginView), string.Empty);

    public static readonly BindableProperty PasswordProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Password), typeof(string), typeof(LoginView), string.Empty);

    public static readonly BindableProperty LoginCommandProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(LoginCommand), typeof(ICommand), typeof(LoginView), null);

    public LoginView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string UserName
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(UserNameProperty); }
        set { SetValue(UserNameProperty,value); }
    }

    public string Password
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(PasswordProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PasswordProperty, value); }
    }

    public ICommand LoginCommand
    {
        get { return (ICommand)GetValue(LoginCommandProperty); }
        set { SetValue(LoginCommandProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

Refractored LoginPage.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:MyAwesomeApp.Controls"
             Title="{Binding Title}"
             x:Class="MyAwesomeApp.Views.LoginPage">

        <controls:LoginView UserName="{Binding UserName}" 
                            Password="{Binding Password}"
                            LoginCommand="{Binding LoginCommand}" />
</ContentPage>
```

What you would end up with for a `LoginView` would in fact be a custom control. While it might be deriving from a Grid, you generally don't care about how I decided to create the layout... You only care that I am giving you some control that has `UserName` and `Password` properties you can attach to and some `LoginCommand` that can execute. It is that inherent difference that in fact makes it a Custom View.

Comment: Could you please explain why to avoid creating a custom page, and how to use custom View as you suggested. Thanks.

Comment: See the explanation in the Edited portion. Hope that helps answer any question you may have.

Comment: Hey @Dans. and thanks for taking the time writing your answer. I am actually pretty familiar with the XF terminology and know what Views and Pages etc. refer to in both XF/Prism. So bottom line, are you suggesting to use a custom `Page` that renders its content between the various toolbars as the base class for all the pages in my app?

Comment: @Shimmy, not at all! What you're talking about is a View object. You could create You might create a custom layout that you reuse across pages for what you're looking to do. Check out out the Xamarin Forms Grid, StackLayout, etc for how you could implement something.

Comment: @Dans. I thought about creating a class that inherits from `Page` but renders its contents surrounded by toolbars, and have all the pages in the app inherit from it, so their content is rendered surrounded with those toolbars.

Comment: @Shimmy I could see an argument if there are predefined Toolbar Items you are using across pages, and you just want a bindable property on the page to attach your command to.

Comment: I have a base viewmodel which exposes the navigation commands anyway, but I'd probably make a custom renderer for the toolbar view too, so I can inject buttons to it.

Answer (score 0):

I have one approach. Not exactly what you want, but could give you food for thought. You could create `SomeBaseContentPage` with `SomeContent` property:

```
public View SomeContent
{
  set
  {
    someGrid.Children.Add(value);
  }
}
```

Then derive your `SomeContentPageA` from `SomeBaseContentPage` and in `XAML` put your specific content into property `<SomeBaseContentPage.SomeContent>`.